# How to access data after asynchronous api call using react/ redux saga ? More info below

Tags: reactjs, api, redux, redux-saga, saga

Tech using: React, Redux, Saga
     how do I access data right after from second function call? The firstFunction keeps executing the rest of the code. I tried async/await, but it does not work.

```
   firstFunction (()=>{
  secondFunctionAPI() //using Redux and Saga
   // Here I want to use the data from the response of secondFunction().
more code...
more code..
})
```

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61952550/how-can-i-fire-an-api-call-with-hooks-and-redux-on-button-click

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the code you want to execute as a callback to `secondFunctionAPI`

```
firstFunction(() => {
  secondFunctionAPI((data) => {
    // Code using data object
  })
})
```

`secondFunctionAPI` would look something like that:

```
secondFunctionAPI = (callback) => {
  API.fetchSomething().then(response => {
    // Call back with data object
    callback(response.data);
  }) 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could invoke second function by dispatching an action after api call like below:

```
const response = yield call(firstFunction);
yield put({ type: 'SOME_ACTION', payload: response.data });
```

Then have a watcher saga defined which will wait for action of type 'SOME_ACTION' and call the handler once this action is dispatched.

`yield takeLatest('SOME_ACTION', second function)`

And then define your handler for 'SOME_ACTION' like:

```
function* secondFunction(action) {
  // here action is the object which was sent as param in put() method earlier
  const { type, payload } = action;
  // your logic here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Approach 1: Callbacks

Like others have noted, you can make `secondFunctionAPI` take in a callback parameter, then call it:

```
firstFunction (() => {
  secondFunctionAPI(() => {
    // More code here...
  });
});
```

## Approach 2: Promises

Convert both functions to use promises, like so:

```
function secondFunctionAPI(){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // do stuff, then:
    resolve();
  });
}
```

Then, call your functions like this:

```
firstFunction().then(() => {
  secondFunctionAPI().then(() => {
    // More code here...
  });
});
```

#### `Promise.all`

If you can call both functions simultaneously (secondFunctionAPI does not need the result of firstFunction to run), you can use this for efficiency:

```
Promise.all([
  firstFunction(), secondFunctionAPI()
]).then(() => {
  // ...
});
```

## Approach 3: `async`/`await`

1. Make your functions return promises, like above.
2. Make a wrapper `async` function.

```
async function doStuff(){
  try { // This is how you would catch rejections
    await firstFunction();
  } catch(error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
  var foo = await secondFunctionAPI(); // This is how you get the result
}
```