# How can i fire an API call with hooks and Redux on button click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

```
const onYesBtnClick = (event, id) => {

    dispatch(deleteMedicine, id);
    setConfirmModal(!setConfirmModal);
  };
```

then I try the same code with callEffect

```
  const onYesBtnClick = useCallback(
    (event, id) => {

      dispatch(deleteMedicine, id);
      setConfirmModal(!setConfirmModal);
    },
    // eslint-disable-next-line
    []
  );
```

deleteMedicine is the function where API calls are executing.

```
   const medList = useSelector((state) => state.medicineReducer.MedicineList);
```

medList holds the data coming from redux.can i directly access medList inside onyesBtnClick

both codes are not working. Is this the right way for API call on button click with redux and hooks

Comment: on **onclick()**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I make an API call on clicking a button in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73692533/how-can-i-make-an-api-call-on-clicking-a-button-in-react)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to dispatch the function by calling it and not by passing as arguments

```
const onYesBtnClick = (event, id) => {
    console.log(medList); // directly access from closure here
    dispatch(deleteMedicine(id)); // call with id
    setConfirmModal(!setConfirmModal);
  };
```

or with useCallback you would write it like

```
const onYesBtnClick = useCallback(
    (event, id) => {
      console.log(medList);
      dispatch(deleteMedicine(id));
      setConfirmModal(prev => !prev); // using callback here is necessary
    },

    [medList] // add as a dependency here
  );
```